# Increase/Expand xfs partition in CentOS 7 (not using LVM)?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

I'm trying to increase the system partition size of my CentOS 7 in vmware machine following the tutorial https://ma.ttias.be/increase-a-vmware-disk-size-vmdk-formatted-as-linux-lvm-without-rebooting/

But there is a difference with my output of `fdisk -l` that I dare not to implement the procedure in the tutorial:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00070da2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    38914047    19456000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        38914048    41924607     1505280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

As you can see, there isn't a LVM mark followed my partition, does that mean I have no need to follow the tutorial in question which is written for LVM partitions? Can I simply use `xfs_growfs /dev/sda1` as [this tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/xfsgrow) says?

By the way, I have increased the size of the underlying storage already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using LVM, so you won't be able to follow the guide you link to. You won't be able to just run `xfs_growfs` either.

You effectively need to [move](https://superuser.com/questions/541067/how-to-move-a-partition-in-gnu-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) the swap partition to the end of the disk and then grow your first partition into the created space. From there you will be able to extend your filesystem. Alternatively you can delete and recreate your swap partition at the end of the disk (probably easier and quicker).

You would first need to turn swap off and delete the swap partition `/dev/sda2`. This will allow you to be able to [extend](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213) `/dev/sda1`. You should then [recreate](http://linuxtechlab.com/create-swap-using-fdisk-fallocate/) the swap partition `/dev/sda2` and update `/etc/fstab` to use the new swap space you created, depending on how the swap space is referenced (e.g. UUID or disk name).

After these steps have been completed you should be able grow the xfs filesystem using xfs_growfs. You may need to reboot / run partprobe before this will work.

Comment: Will my data be erased with the easier method: delete and recreate the first partition?

Comment: No, as when you turn the swap off, everything stores on the swap partition will moves back into ram. You can turn swap off using swappoff -a